# How to prepare PHP multidimensional arrays for Laravel Mass updateOrCreate()?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, mass-assignment, laravel-5.6

I am trying to mass insert into Laravel (5.6) Model. Having issues with array preparations; It returns

```
lluminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' 
(SQL: insert into `_geolocation` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) values 
(Manchester,+UK, Manchester,+UK, Manchester,+UK, Manchester,+UK, 
Manchester,+UK))
```

I am generating arrays like this:

```
if($outputTo->status->message == "OK"){ // if
    for ($i = 0; $i < $outputTo->total_results; $i++) {
        //print_r($outputFrom->results[$i]->geometry->lat);
        $geodata_b [] =[
            $formattedAddrTo,
            $outputTo->results[$i]->formatted,
            $outputTo->results[$i]->geometry->lat,
            $outputTo->results[$i]->geometry->lng,
            ];
    }
}
```

This are my array`s output;

```
    array:5 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Manchester,+UK"
    1 => "Manchester, Greater Manchester, England, United Kingdom"
    2 => 53.4791301
    3 => -2.2441009
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Manchester,+UK"
    1 => "Chapel Street Primary School, Chapel Street, Manchester M19 3GH, United Kingdom"
    2 => 53.443957
    3 => -2.1858478
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Manchester,+UK"
    1 => "The Manchester, Lytham Road, Bispham FY1 6AH, United Kingdom"
    2 => 53.8067298
    3 => -3.0549142
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Manchester,+UK"
    1 => "The Manchester, Bromsgrove Road, Bromsgrove B62 0HH, United Kingdom"
    2 => 52.4003403
    3 => -2.0539726
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Manchester,+UK"
    1 => "The Harlequin, Spitalfields, Sheffield S3 8GG, United Kingdom"
    2 => 53.3884864
    3 => -1.4663405
  ]
]
```

Inserting code;

```
    $geolCache = \App\Geolocation::updateOrCreate([$geodata_b]);
```

My Model;

```
protected $fillable = ['adrr','faddr','lat','lng'];
```

Please could anybody help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following key-value pairs. Try this code

```html
if($outputTo->status->message == "OK"){ // if
    for ($i = 0; $i < $outputTo->total_results; $i++) {
        $geodata_b [] = [
            'adrr' => $formattedAddrTo,
            'faddr' => $outputTo->results[$i]->formatted,
            'lat' => $outputTo->results[$i]->geometry->lat,
            'lng' => $outputTo->results[$i]->geometry->lng,
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer; i tried your code but unfortunately i am now getting this error ; Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  ... Please help!

Comment: Got it working in the end. thanks a lot for your help.